# Characters of representation equal up to constant, how can one relate the vector spaces?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ is an infinite group with two representations $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ and $\tau: G \rightarrow GL(W)$ for finite-dimensional vector spaces $V, W$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\chi_{\rho}$ and $\chi_{\tau}$ be the corresponding characters for the rep's $\rho, \tau$.

**Q1:** If $G$ is finite, it is known that if $\chi_{\rho} = \chi_{\tau}$ then $V \cong W$. Can we say the same for infinite $G$?

**Q2:** What if the characters are equal up to a constant multiple, say $\chi_{\rho} = 2\chi_{\tau}$? Can we still relate the spaces $V$ and $W$ somehow? Or at least can we "extend" the pair $(G, \tau, W)$ (whatever that means) to get equivalent characters?

I'm new to representation theory and am reading some notes currently, but I could not find any information on this particular problem.

Comment: Since you have $W \leq V$, can't you just check the character values at the identity element? This should give you the dimensions of $V$ and $W$, then you only need to check whether $\dim W = \dim V$.

Comment: @Joppy that was meant to say $V \neq W$, but I suppose that doesn’t even matter so I edited it out.

Comment: In that case no: consider the group $(\mathbb{C}, +)$. Let $V$ be the two-dimensional trivial representation, and $W$ the representation $\pi(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then the trace of every matrix in both representations is $2$.

Comment: @Joppy Great example!